# how can i change the OpenIddict AccessToken Lifetime in apb 7？

Tags: abp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VES0.png)
How to change the default expiration time of accesstoken?

Comment: it's default value is 3600 seconds , i want to chang it  bigger

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your module

```cs
 context.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    ...
                })
                .AddAbpOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    ...
                   
                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = validatedContext =>
                    {
                        validatedContext.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                        validatedContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(365);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

Comment: thanks , i founded it PreConfigure<OpenIddictServerBuilder>(builder =>
{
    builder
        .SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365))
        .SetIdentityTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
});